# Android's Java SDK from Command Line?

Tags: java, android

I have Android studio installed, can I use its version of Java from the command line to test java code? I am on Windows 10 64bit. I just installed the Android Studio on 170827. Thanks

Comment: if you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, then sure, you can

Comment: Worked great thanks. I was used to Java (normal SDK not Android Studio) being in the x64 dir. Your comment made me look in the x86 dir and it was there added the JAVA_HOME and then the path to the bin in Path. It works great. Thanks